# Child component's state does not change while rendering

Tags: reactjs, github-api

I am a novice to ReactJs so please bear with me. I am trying to build a project from [this](https://www.udemy.com/reactjs-and-flux-learn-by-building-10-projects/) course called Git-Hub profile viewer. Here is my code for Parent component:

```
import Profile from './github/Profile.jsx';


class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      username: 'xxxx',
      userData: [],
      userRepos: [],
      perPage: 5
    }
  }
  // get user data from github
  getUserData(){
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://api.github.com/users/' +this.state.username+'?client_id='+this.props.clientId+'&client_secret='+this.props.clientSecret,
      dataType:'json',
      cache:false,
      success: function(data){
        this.setState({userData:data});
        console.log(data);
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err){
        this.setState({userData: null});
        alert(err);
      }.bind(this)
    });
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    this.getUserData();
  }
    render(){
      return (
        <div>
        <Profile userData = {this.state.userData} />
        </div>
      )

  }

}

App.propTypes = {
  clientId: React.PropTypes.string,
  clientSecret: React.PropTypes.string
};
App.defaultProps = {
  clientId: 'some_genuine_client_Id',
  clientSecret:'some_really_client_secret'

}
export default App;
```

and here is my child's component:

```
class Profile extends Component {


    render() {
      return (
        <div className="panel panel-default">
            <div className="panel-heading">
            <h3 className="panel-title">{this.props.userData.name}</h3>
          </div>
          <div className="panel-body">

          </div>
        </div>
      )

  }
}

export default Profile;
```

Problem is that the props in child component does not update its state while rendering the page although the data retrieval is successful from Git-Hub as shown in console log. What am I doing wrong, can somebody please help?

Comment: You are defining `userData` as an array but accessing it as an object. Which one is the correct type?

Comment: Can you do `componentDidUpdate() { console.log(this.props.userData); }` in the `Profile` component? Then we can see whether it's actually being retrieved and passed down to the child from the parent. Also if you put some PropTypes for the Profile component, and use `.isRequired` on the `userData` property, React will warn you when it doesn't receive that prop in the component.

Comment: I did componentDidMount() { console.log(this.props.userData); } in the Profile component, it is giving as empty array. Like this:
[]length: 0__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: The other way this could be done is to pass the `getUserData()` function down as a prop to the Profile component, then call that on `componentDidMount()` in the Profile. Set the state in Profile to have User Data (empty array/object - choose one!), and the `getUserData` function to *return* the data, not setState in the parent. Assign the result to a variable in the Profile, then set the state to that variable. I'll get some code written upon for you soon if you want.

Comment: yes, that would be a great help

Answer (score 0):

So firstly, you should be ensuring that you are accessing `userData` in the correct way, as @mersocarlin mentioned. This is quite likely to be the cause of your problem.

Theoretically, your way of doing this should work. However I've written a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/33q1kpjn/1/) for you as an example. I couldn't make the Ajax call so have simulated it with a `setTimeout` event over 5 seconds.

The other way of doing this is to pass down the `getUserData` function to the child component (Profile) and let it handle the call itself. Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/33q1kpjn/) for that, and the code below:

```
class Profile extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      userData: {}
    };
  }

    componentDidMount() {
      const userData = this.props.getUserData();
      console.log(userData);
      this.setState({ userData: userData });
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div className="panel panel-default">
            <div className="panel-heading">
            <h3 className="panel-title">Hello, {this.state.userData.name || 'World'}</h3>
          </div>
          <div className="panel-body">

          </div>
        </div>
      )

  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  getUserData(){
    return {
      'name': 'Tom'
    }
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <Profile getUserData={this.getUserData} />
    )
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should call `getUserData()` in `componentWillMount` rather than `componentDidMount` to get the data before the component has rendered. And then in the child component use a life cycle method `componentWillReceiveProps` to check if the child component is getting the right props and updating the state accordingly. It'll be something like this:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if(this.props.userData !== nextProps.userData) {
    console.log('condition met');
    this.setState({
      userData: nextProps.userData
    });
  }
}
```

Try this and let me know, I'll help you further.